# Move store procedure from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have MS SQL Server database include table and store procedure. I want to move my databases to MySQL, but Migration wizard in MySQL just only move table. How can I move both table and store procedure? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suppose you must rewrite SP because the functions can be different between PL and Transact

Comment: You must rewrite the procedure

Comment: I have so  many sp ,it make me lost so much time.

Comment: There are some tools that at least claim to do the conversion, for example you can try [sqlines tool](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-mysql) and doing a simple search finds you more alternatives